# How to denote that two matrices have the same size, without using notation for the number of rows and columns?

Tags: matrices, notation, index-notation

How can I write that a matrix, e.g., $A_{p×q}$ has the same size as matrix $B_{m×n}$, i.e. $p=m$ and $q=n$, without using variables $p,q,m,n$, just the symbols for $A$ and $B$?

Comment: No standardized notation using a single symbol exists.  You could always *define* a symbol though to mean this or create new notation.  For example you could define $\approx_{\text{size}}$ to mean what you want.  That being said, if it is only going to be used briefly a few times at a time, it takes much less effort to just say "$A$ and $B$ are both of the same dimensions."

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with "$A$ and $B$ have the same dimensions"? Math writing is invented and used for the sake of communication, so if words can explain something in a short, concise and precise way, why make it more difficult than it has to?

If you have a need to write that phrase a lot of times in a relatively small amount of text, you could define a symbol for it, if you'd like. But that's up to you.